# Unset attempt causes MongoError: Invalid modifier $unset

Tags: mongodb

Issuing the MongoDB commands:

`db.foo.insert({ x: "foo", y: "bar" })`
`db.foo.update({ x: "foo" }, { $unset: { y: 1 } })`

Causes this error: `MongoError: Invalid modifier $unset`

As I understand it, per the [Update Operators: $unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/unset/) portion of the MongoDB docs, this should work flawlessly.

*Shell Version: 2.4.4* - Installation (Ubuntu 10.04): mongodb-10gen_2.4.4_amd64.deb

MongoDB log says: `update test.foo query: { x: "foo" } exception userassert:Invalid modifier specified $unset 0ms`

Comment: it works fine for me.  is that an exact cut-n-paste?  if so what exact version is this - check both version() and db.version()

Comment: Yes, copying your command and pasting it into the Mongo 2.2.3 shell on my computer works for me.  You must be using an outdated buggy version (current 2.4 version is 2.4.4) or one that was improperly installed or have some sort of character encoding weirdness going on.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Issuing the command version() returns 2.4.4 but db.version() returns 1.2.2! Looking into that right now.

Comment: so, your server is half the version of your shell :)  so you only get half of $set and $unset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that although the MongoDB version was in fact 2.4.4, the *database* version was 1.2.2. Even though I had recently upgraded the mongod version to latest, I neglected to stop the mongod process itself.

The solution was simple (I am using a config file):

`mongod --dbpath /data/db --shutdown`
`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

This effectively upgraded my database version to 2.4.4 :)